MercadoPago Payment devuelve null
Cuando ejecuto una venta desde el backend el $payment me devuelve null:
Lo he realizado de acuerdo a la documentación:
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken(privateKey);
$payment = new MercadoPago\Payment();            
$payment->transaction_amount = (float)$data->transaction_amount;
$payment->token = $data->token;
$payment->installments = (int)$data->installments;
$payment->payment_method_id = $data->payment_method_id;
$payment->issuer_id = (int)$data->issuer_id;
$payer = new MercadoPago\Payer();
$payer->email = $data->payer->email;

$payment->payer = $payer;

$payment->save();
     

Pero cuando imprimo algo como:
echo $payment->status
Me devuelve solo null.
Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias

y si preguntas en la comunidad de mercado pago???
